# Load Failure occurred on device TAP01 on IBM Power System

Tags: ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I have problem with tape of type Ultrium 5. This tape I can't take daily backup from system on it message appears to me says that:

> Load Failure occurred on device  tap01.

I can't get it out from the IBM Server and the small screen above the tape part in the IBM Server machine shows the number (6 and !).

Comment: If you need "urgent" help with a hardware problem, you almost certainly need to call for IBM hardware support.

Comment: are there any solutions or troubleshooting I can do or not ?

Comment: This isn't a programming question; the people who might help you aren't monitoring this forum.  A more appropriate forum is Server Fault (I think).  You probably don't have an AS/400 - LTO5 tapes don't attach to a machine that old.  You probably have a Power 6 or Power 7 running IBM i.  That's important because when you search the web you'll get better results if you search with the right terms. Edit your question and add the tape device number (like TS2900) and the exact error message, including the first and second level text (CPF2001 Load failure occurred on device TAP01, resource TAPMLB01)

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic (_Server Fault_ would be better).